# Why does DrRacket seem to identify this as a tail call?

Tags: scheme, racket, tail-recursion

Consider this snippet:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (f i)
  (if (> i 5)
      0
      (+ 1 (f (+ 1 i)))))
```

Here, the call to `f` is not in tail position, and when I debug, I see a growing stack of the form

```
(+ ...)
(f ...)
(f ...)
(f ...)
(f ...)
```

This is expected. However, when I hover over the beginning of the last line, a light purple arrow appears and points to the beginning of the function definition. If I understand the documentation correctly, it indicates tail position. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form which is the last line *is* in tail position with respect to `f`.  The recursive call to `f`, however, isn't: if you hover over the `f` you'll get a pale blue arrow which tells you that it's the same `f` the function is binding.  Here's a screenshot showing both things:

[image: arrows]

All of the `(if ...)` form and both of its consequents are in tail position.  The `f` is the same `f` defined by the function, but is not in tail position.

Answer (score 0):

When you move to B and you see A ➯ B. It means you can find B's define in A.

[image]

[image]

When you move to A and you see A ➯ B. You can see variable bound occurrence.

[image]

[image]